# Where can I find Documentation on the Java SimpleFormatter format strings?

Tags: java, logging, string-formatting

I'm trying to modify a logging.properties file that uses the java SimpleFormatter.
I can set the
      java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = ""
property, but I can't find documentation on what you can put in it.
I've found several examples, but NONE of them tell me what the possibilities are.
They just say that "%4$s: %5$s [%1$tc]%n" does such-and-such.
I'm hoping that some docs exist somewhere.

Comment: The API is the best source as is often the case. It has a line "See Also: " that will refer you to the [Formatter class entry in the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) where you'll see what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the API docs. The docs for [java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter#format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format%28java.util.logging.LogRecord%29) give a link to [java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) which has detailed information about formatting syntax in Java. (In other words, I'm repeating the comment from @HovercraftFullOfEels.)

Comment: I thought that looked familiar! But heck I'll up vote ya because it's shear genius.

Comment: Believe it or not, I actually had missed that link in the javadocs.  So I hadn't seen that.  Hmm, actually, I'm thinking I was looking at some old page somewhere else, as that looks different from what I saw yesterday.  Gotta be more careful with my random Google searches.